# Tkinter Text Animation?

Tags: python, animation, text, tkinter

would it be possible in any way to do a text animation in Tkinter or Python in general? (Although the program is based in Tkinter)

For example, maybe the characters of the text appearing one after another kind of like you are typing it very fast.  Is there any way to do this?

Thanks so much.

Comment: yes it possible. Use `root.after` to run repeatedly function which changes text on Label.

Answer (score 3):

Example - display current time on label.

`after()` runs `update_time` after 1s and `update_time` uses `after()` to runs itself again after 1s. This way `update_time` is called many times and it can change label many times.

```
import tkinter as tk # Python 3.x
import time

# function which changes time on Label 
def update_time():
    # change text on Label
    lbl['text'] = time.strftime('Current time: %H:%M:%S')

    # run `update_time` again after 1000ms (1s)
    root.after(1000, update_time) # function name without ()


# create window
root = tk.Tk()

# create label for current time
lbl = tk.Label(root, text='Current time: 00:00:00')
lbl.pack()

# run `update_time` first time after 1000ms (1s)
root.after(1000, update_time) # function name without ()
#update_time() # or run first time immediately

# "start the engine"
root.mainloop()
```