# Error moving rectangle in canvas using tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I make a square and make it move though when i exit it brings an error. What am i doing wrong? Thanks

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time


root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, height=500, width=500)
canvas.pack()

a = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50)


for i in range(0, 60):
    canvas.move(a,5,0)
    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)


root.mainloop()
```

And this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Brad\Test.py", line 17, in <module>
    canvas.move(a,5,0)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2434, in move
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'move') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".57748176"
```

Comment: use `root.after` instead of `for` loop  and `sleep`

Comment: Can you please explain, I am new to this and do not understand your answer

Comment: it is no answer for question. It is only suggestion to your code. `mainloop` starts program and do many things - handle events, redraw widgets on the screen, etc, Using loops and sleep you stops `mainloop` job.

Comment: Thank you! I had quit the window whilst it was moving and so it brought the error, but when i let the loop finish, then exited,  there was no error. By any chance, do you how i can prevent that?

Comment: @NoamNeumann: The easiest way would be to use a try block and catch the `TclError` that gets thrown.

Comment: there are many examples how to use after - for example to display current time - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34940146/1832058 - you can use it to move rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many examples how to use `after` to run something repeatedly.

`after` is better solution than `for` loop and `sleep` - it is part of `tkinter`.

`after` adds time and function name to special list and `mainloop` will  call this function.

```
from tkinter import *

# --- functions ---

def move_rectangle():

    # move rectangle 
    canvas.move(a,5,0)

    # run `move_rectangle` again after 100ms (0.1s)
    root.after(100, move_rectangle) # function name without ()

# --- main ----

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, height=500, width=500)
canvas.pack()

a = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50)

# run `move_rectangle` first time after 100ms (0.1s)
root.after(100, move_rectangle) # function name without ()
#move_rectangle() # or run first time immediately

# "start the engine"
root.mainloop()
```

-

btw: If you will need to run long-running function then you will need threads.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful, but i don't know what threads are, another time