# Tkinter - Coordinates

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a little project from a Pi2Go robot, where it will get data from the ultrasonic sensor, then place an X if it see's a object and O where it currently is, I've got two questions: 
How do I set a coordinate position on tkinter? For example I wanted to insert text at 0,0, or 120,120.

Secondly:
How do I get tkinter to constantly update the map I'm building
Cheers!

Comment: To place widgets by coordinates have a look at the [`place`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) geometry manager. You could try to place label widgets with the desired letters on given coordinates. Since this might become a bit ugly and unperformant, you might consider a totally different approach using e.g. Pygame (should be capable to solve your task, but I never used it). For me, this looks more than a game than a GUI task to solve since it is more or less dynamic rendering of objects. However, if you provide some sample coordinates I could give it a try, if you're still stuck...

Comment: you can use `root.after()` to call function frequently and update map - see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34940146/1832058

Comment: @albert Let's say 120,120 90,90 30,30 and place X on all of em

Comment: Okay. But what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just cobbled some code together to give you a short introduction in how to use the `place` geometry manager. For further explanation please see comments in code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

from tkinter import *


# init our application's root window
root = Tk()
root.geometry('480x480')


# let's provide same sample coordinates with the desired text as tuples in a list
coords = [(30,30,'X'), (90,90,'X'), (120,120,'X'), (240,240,'X'), (270,270,'X'), (360,360,'O')]


# interate through the coords list and read the coordinates and the text of each tuple
for c in coords:
    l = Label(root, text=c[2])
    l.place(x=c[0], y=c[1])


# start a loop over the application
root.mainloop()
```

I am using Python 3. If you are using Python 2, you need to change `tkinter` to `Tkinter`. That should do the trick if you need to port my code to Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

use the .place function.

like in the following

```
label = Label(root, text = 'i am placed')
#places the label in the following x and y coordinates
label.place(20,20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class buildWorld:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=800)

        self.canvas.pack()
        self.tmp = Image.new('RGBA', (1000,800), color=(0,0,0) )
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.tmp)
        self.Land = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=self.img)

        self.tmp = Image.new('RGBA', (50, 50), color=(255, 0, 0))
        self.img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.tmp)
        self.mob1 = self.canvas.create_image(125, 125, anchor='nw', image=self.img1)


        self.tmp = Image.new('RGBA', (50, 50), color=(0, 255, 0))
        self.img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.tmp)
        self.mob2 = self.canvas.create_image(300, 300, anchor='nw', image=self.img2)

root = Tk()
world = buildWorld(root)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to use `place` method whit arguments of your X and Y coordinates.

```
label = Label(root, text = 'Placed On X and Y')
label.place(x= X,y = Y)
```

or another way is to use `pack` method which will take arguments like:

```
label.pack(padx = W,pady = H)
```

where W and H are the distances from center points to your coordinates X and Y.