# Count down error

Tags: python, tkinter, countdown

This code generates an error and I am not sure why or how to resolve it?

```
File "/Users/johnz/Dropbox/PythonWorkspace/BumpersRev1/test3.py", 
  line 7, in countdown
if self.remaining <= 0:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'remaining'`
```

.

```
from tkinter import *

# count down timer
def countdown(self, remaining = None):
    if remaining is not None:
        self.remaining = remaining
    if self.remaining <= 0:
        pass
    else:
        self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
        self.after(1000, self.countdown)

def main():
# create a Tk window
    win1 = Tk()
    countdown(90)
    mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to pass an integer into the function countdown. It should be noted that `self` is conventional. It is not required to be named that, but it is what we generally use. However, because this is not an instance function (i.e. is not part of a class) then you have no reason to inherit the object itself. This can be done without the self entirely.

```
import functools
from Tkinter import *
def countdown(remaining = None):
    if remaining <= 0 or remaining is None:
        pass
    else:
        remaining -= 1
        # Requires a widget instance here....
        # Widget.after(1000, functools.partial(countdown, remaining))
```

Comment: I replace my countdown function with your code, leaving everything else in place. I added the import. Now I get a new error:   

File "/Users/johnz/Dropbox/PythonWorkspace/BumpersRev1/test3.py", line 10, in countdown
    after(1000, functools.partial(countdown(remaining)))
NameError: name 'after' is not defined

Comment: I would expect you to. You still need to deal with using a Widget instance with After. Unfortunately, I don't use Tkinter often enough to know about it, but I immediately recognized your usage of self as erroneous.

Comment: Also, refresh the page to get my most recent edit. I've assumed after is a function you've already used or can access. AFAIK, it's in Tkinter.Widget.after

Comment: I really appreciate your answers but I must be having a bad day. Trying to understand the connection between the widget and the .after function. What happens to the widget when the .after function is applied or put a different way, will any widget do even if it is only used as a placeholder if you will? Am I making sense?

Comment: `After` is some gui element changes ! After a label, frame, root, so tracing any one changes!

Comment: Thanks for your help with the code. I was able to rework my code based on your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send arguments in `after`

```
from tkinter import *

# count down timer
def countdown(remaining, widget):
    print(remaining)

    if remaining > 0:
        remaining = remaining - 1
        widget.after(1000, countdown, remaining, widget)

def main():
    win1 = Tk()
    countdown(90, win1)
    mainloop()

main()
```

If `win1` will be global variable then you don't have to send `widget`

```
from tkinter import *

# count down timer
def countdown(remaining):
    print(remaining)

    if remaining > 0:
        remaining = remaining - 1
        win1.after(1000, countdown, remaining)


# global variables
win1 = Tk()
countdown(90)
mainloop()
```

BTW: example with `after` adn displaying current time in tkinter window: 
[Tkinter Text Animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34940146/1832058)